# What is the closed form or analytical expression of the distribution of p-values, if we *don't* test point Null hypotheses?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, p-value

#### Problem

If we test a true point Null hypothesis using a continuously distributed test statistic, it is possible to prove that the $p$-value resulting from such test is a realisation of a uniform distribution (see for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367749/proof-that-p-value-is-uniformly-distributed-when-the-null-hypothesis-is-true/367752#367752) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240121/formal-proof-that-p-values-are-uniformly-distributed)). For these specific cases, the probability density function of the $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ distribution offers a closed form expression of the distribution of $p$-values under the Null.

However, uniformity breaks down if we test true **composite** Null hypotheses (as pointed out by @whuber [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10617/101974) and addressed in these questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58929/is-the-p-value-still-uniformly-distributed-when-the-null-hypothesis-is-composite) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308791/p-value-distribution-under-null-hypothesis-and-discrete-data)) or if we test **false** Null hypotheses. In these cases, as well as for cases [in which a discrete test statistic is used](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153249/non-uniform-distribution-of-p-values-when-simulating-binomial-tests-under-the-nu/153267#153267), we can approximate the distribution of the $p$-values using repeated simulations of the same statistical test.

Now, I was wondering whether it is also possible to find a closed form or analytical expression of the distribution of $p$-values in any of these cases - and if yes, how. A solution to the following example would be enough to get me started, I think.

#### Concrete example

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $\sigma^2$ known. Let us then state the following two hypotheses:

$$\begin{align} H_0: \mu \leq \mu_0 \text{ vs } H_1: \mu > \mu_0 \end{align}$$

Let us furthermore assume that $\mu$ is strictly smaller than $\mu_0$, say $\mu = 0 < \mu_0 =  1$. Under these assumptions and using any test statistic that is feasible, what is the closed form or analytical expression of the distribution of the $p$-values?

Comment: The answer is yes, because this is precisely the information used to compute the *power* of a test. That indicates just how broad this question is.  Is there a specific problem you need to address?

Comment: @whuber I restated the question slightly so as to also include the question *what* the closed form expression is. I don't need it for a specific problem, but to gain a better general understanding of the distributional properties of p-values.  A solution to example stated would already be enough to get me started, I think.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think this is possible to compute without any further assumptions on $\mu$. The distribution of $p$-values will be different for any given true $\mu$, and it's impossible to know it without knowing the value of $\mu$. @whuber What did you have in mind when you answered "yes"?

Comment: @amoeba I had in mind performing the computation for all $\mu.$  The result is a parameterized family of distributions.

Comment: @amoeba How would the computation work if we fix $\mu$ to a specific value. Say, $\mu_0 = 1$ and $\mu = 0$?

Comment: I don't know (would have to think about it) but I am sure it's computable. If this is what you are asking then please edit to clarify.

Comment: Done - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let mu_0=0, mu=-1, sigma=1, and sample size n. Then you can use z-test with z-statistic distributed as N(-1, 1/n). P-value is equal to 1-F(z), where F() is standard normal CDF. Not sure how much of a closed form you can get here...